# Explosive Plant/Chemotrophs

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design

I'm looking for an autotroph that produces an explosive compound for either reproductive or defensive purposes that an intellegent alien could harvest and domesticate for the purposes of producing propellents for their firearms. The atmosphere has a high presence of hydrogen sulfide in the atmosphere there are a lot of chemosynthetic 'plants' as well as photosynthetic autotrophs.

The atmosphere is 4.3 times denser than ours which would make the concussive effects of explosives more dangerous while making shrapnel less so due to increased air resistance.

What kinds (if any) of chemicals could a plant make that could be used as a firearm propellent? Would it be a nitrate similar to modern smokeless powder? Or would the presence of sulfer in the environment make a substance like black powder more likely? Or is there some other compound that would be more plausible?

Comment: Maybe this question of mine could have some satisfactory answers? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/185608/how-can-my-exploding-fungus-plant-explode